# eclipse skips main function instead of executing it

Tags: c

I am using eclipse 3.2020 on WIN10 and I have a problem executing my main function.

When I run the program as it is, I get no output to conole, even when I add a printf in the first line, and the exit code is -1,073,741,819. When I comment out/ delete the line  `solve(s);`  the code run as intended and gives exit code 0.

Edit: added full code (both solve and print_sol are in solver.c)

Edit 2: As mentioned in the comments, the problem was in the code (bug) and not eclipse, I just assumed that an error message will be printed if there is one.

p.s.: I still find the fact a printf in the start won't print if there is a runtime error in another part of the main function quite weird.

main.c:

```
#include "solver.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int **grid = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
        grid[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    }
    int mat[4][4] = {{1,0,3,0}
                     ,{2,0,0,0}
                     ,{3,0,0,0}
                     ,{4,2,0,0}};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            grid[i][j] = mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    solver *s = create_solver(4, &grid);
    solve(s);
    print_sol(s);
}
```

solver.h:

```
#ifndef SOLVER_H_
#define SOLVER_H_

typedef struct sudoku_solver solver;

/*creates a new solver using the length of one row of the board.
 *Then, the user will follow the instructions on screen to input the board*/
solver* create_solver(int row_len, int ***input_board_ptr);

/*if solver is NULL, an error will appear.
 *Otherwise, The board that was given won't be changed, and neither
 *the solver nor the solution (unless saved before using get_sol)
 *will be accessible after this*/
void destroy_solver(solver *solver);

/*if solver is NULL, an error will appear.
 *Otherwise, it will solve the inputed board*/
void solve(solver *solver);

/*if "solve" wasn't executed before, an error will appear.
 *Otherwise, it will print a solution to the inputed board*/
void print_sol(solver *solver);

/*if "solve" wasn't executed before, an error will appear.
 *Otherwise, returns a solution to the inputed board as a matrix of integers*/
int** get_sol(solver *solver);

#endif /* SOLVER_H_ */
```

solver.c:

```
#include "solver.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*the board will be represented by an array of size NxN.
 *the value of every board cell is between 0 and N when 0
 *means "default value"*/
typedef struct sudoku_solver{
    /*length of one row of the board*/
    int N;
    /*a pointer to the solution board*/
    int ***sol_ptr;
}solver;



solver* create_solver(int row_len, int ***input_board_ptr){
    solver *s = (solver*) malloc(sizeof(solver));
    /*throw an ERROR if the malloc failed*/

    /*row_len is a variable, so we have to declare everything dynamically */
    /*allocating the sol matrix as an array of pointers (1 out of 2D)*/
    int **sol = (int**) malloc(row_len * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < row_len; i++){
        /*allocating every row (the second D)
         *while making sol equal to input_board*/
        sol[i] = (int*) malloc(row_len * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < row_len; j++){
            sol[i][j] =  (*input_board_ptr)[i][j];
        }
    }

    s->N = row_len;
    /*if row_len != pow(sqrt(row_len),2) then throw invalid input ERROR*/
    s->sol_ptr = &sol;
    return s;
}

void destroy_solver(solver *s){
    for (int i = 0; i < s->N; i++){
        free((*(s->sol_ptr))[i]);
    }
    free(*(s->sol_ptr));
    free(s->sol_ptr);
    free(s);
}


int* calc_next(int x, int y, int *next, solver *s);

bool isSafe(int x, int y, int val, solver *s);

bool solve_rec(int x, int y, solver *s);

void solve(solver *s){
    int n = s->N;
    int next[2];
    int ***sp = s->sol_ptr;

    //find next empty space
    if ((*sp)[0][0] == 0){
        next[0] = 0;
        next[1] = 1;
    }
    else{
        calc_next(0, 0, next, s);
    }

    int nextX = next[0];
    int nextY = next[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (isSafe(nextX, nextY, i, s)){
            (*sp)[nextX][nextY] = i;
            if(solve_rec(nextX, nextY, s)){
                return;
            }
            //backtrack
            (*sp)[nextX][nextY] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("no sol");
    return;
}

bool solve_rec(int x, int y, solver *s){
    int n = s->N;
    int next[2];
    int ***sp = s->sol_ptr;

    if (x == n - 1 && y == n - 1){
        return true;
    }

    //find next empty space
    calc_next(x, y, next, s);

    int nextX = next[0];
    int nextY = next[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (isSafe(nextX, nextY, i, s)){
            (*sp)[nextX][nextY] = i;
            if(solve_rec(nextX, nextY, s)){
                return true;
            }
            //backtrack
            (*sp)[nextX][nextY] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool isSafe(int x, int y, int val, solver *s){
    int n = s->N;
    int ***sp = s->sol_ptr;
    /*check row*/
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if ((*sp)[x][j] == val){
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*check col*/
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if ((*sp)[i][y] == val){
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*check block
     *the index of a block in a grid is just like the index of entry in block.
     *In sudoku, there are bs*bs blocks, and each has bs rows and bs columns*/
    int bs = sqrt(n); // block size
    int block_x_index = x / bs;
    int block_y_index = y / bs;
    for(int i = block_x_index * bs; i < bs * (block_x_index + 1); i++){
        for(int j = block_y_index * bs; j < bs * (block_y_index + 1); j++){
            if ((*sp)[i][j] == val){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/*assuming x,y is not the last place in the grid,
 * finds the next empty place after it*/
int* calc_next(int x, int y, int *next, solver *s){
    int n;
    int ***sp = s->sol_ptr;
    /*find the first empty place*/
    do{
        n = s->N;
        if (y == n - 1){
            x++;
            y = 0;
        }
        else{
            y++;
        }

    }while ((*sp)[x][y] != 0);
    next[0] = x;
    next[1] = y;
    return next;
}

void print_sol(solver *s){
    int n = s->N;
    int bs = sqrt(n); // block size
    char curr;
    int rows_passed, col_passed;
    for (int i = 0; i < n + bs - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n + bs - 1; j++){
            //if it's a grid row
            if (i == bs || ((i - bs) % (bs + 1)) == 0){
                //if it's also a grid col
                if (j == bs || ((j - bs) % (bs + 1) == 0)){
                    curr = '+';
                }
                else{
                    curr = '-';
                }
            }
            //if it's only a grid col
            else if (j == bs || ((j - bs) % (bs + 1) == 0)){
                curr = '|';
            }
            else{
                rows_passed = i / (bs + 1);
                col_passed = j / (bs + 1);
                curr = '0' + (*(s->sol_ptr))[i-rows_passed][j-col_passed];
            }
            printf("%c",curr);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int** get_sol(solver *solver){
    return *(solver->sol_ptr);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1. Eclipse does not execute anything - it is just a very complicated text editor with zilions of plugins alowing compilation, debug and plenty other functions.

Comment: How to reproduce this issue?What does solve() func do?

Comment: Any compilation errors reported in the console?

Comment: 1) Eclipse likely isn't the problem: we need to review your code, first. 2) "main() doesn't execute" ... or "nothing prints"?  Do we know which?  Are you merely *ASSUMING* main() didn't execute just because you didn't see anythning?  3) *WHAT DOES `print_sol()` do???*  SUGGESTION: Try reproducing with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
@codegorilla ,added the full code. It should solve the sudoku board with backtracking  but I haven't debugged it yet.

Comment: FWIW: exit status 1073741819 in hex is 0xc0000005, better known as STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: @Pam no compilation errors at all, there are only warning about unused variables in main.

Comment: @paulsm4 added the full code. About 2, I think it won't execute at all- I tried to debug it and the program just fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please learn how to use your debugger.  In this case, it would take you directly to the problem: you're crashing with an access violation (Windows 0xc0000005) here:

```
void solve(solver *s) {
    int n = s->N;
    int next[2];
    int ***sp = s->sol_ptr;

    //find next empty space
    if ((*sp)[0][0] == 0) {  // <-- Access violation here: "sp" incorrectly initialized!
        next[0] = 0;
        next[1] = 1;
    }
```

The underlying problem is that although sudoku_solver.N was initialized to "4" ... sudoku_solver.sol_ptr[0][0] is pointing to uninitialized memory.

PS:

Yes, it's very definitely "executing". It wouldn't crash if it didn't run ;)